# How to union many dataframes based on column order with casting to timestamp

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, union

I have many dataframes whose columns have the same order (the column name may differ for each dataframe). And there are 2 columns with a `timestamp` type but the problem is that in some dataframes, it has a `date` type. So I cannot merge it with `union` function.

I want to `union` all these dataframe but I don't want to cast `to_timestamp` for each dataframe.

My approach is to change the type of the first dataframe, then the remaining dataframe will follow the type of the first one but it does not work.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def change_type_timestamp(df):
    df = df.withColumn("A", F.to_timestamp(F.col("A"))) \
        .withColumn("B", F.to_timestamp(F.col("B")))
    return df

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...]

dfs[0] = change_type_timestamp(dfs[0])
reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), dfs)
```

How can I `union` all the dataframe without changing the type of each dataframe one-by-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find column index by providing first dataframe's column names. And then reference columns in other dataframes based on the index.

Setup:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-02-02 08:08:08', 1, '2020-02-02 07:07:07')], ['A', 'x', 'B'])
df1.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- A: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- x: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- B: string (nullable = true)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-02-02 08:08:08', 1, '2020-02-02 07:07:07')], ['C', 'x', 'D'])
df2.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- C: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- x: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- D: string (nullable = true)
```

Script:

```py
dfs = [df1, df2]
cols = ['A', 'B']
indexes = [dfs[0].columns.index(c) for c in cols]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    for j in indexes:
        c = dfs[i].columns[j]
        dfs[i] = dfs[i].withColumn(c, F.to_timestamp(c))

df = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), dfs)
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- A: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- x: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- B: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler, neater and readable way would be as follows. You may have to convert the timestamps and dates to strings and back. datetime always takes precedence in such a situations.

```
cols=df1.columns
dfs =[df1, df2]
df_list =[]
for df in dfs:
  df_list.append(df.toDF(*cols))
  
newdf=reduce(lambda a, b: b.unionByName(a), df_list)

newdf.printSchema()
```

Comment: Nice :) Renaming columns using `toDF` looks way simpler than finding and using indexes in my answer. It was probably not accepted, because `to_timestamp` part is missing.